# How to follow the latest updates in HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css, web-standards

Clearly HTML (and not XHTML) is the future. Now, the official specs of HTML and CSS by W3C (like [this one for example](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)) are not very beginner friendly or at least readable.

So, are there any alternatives for beginners so that we can follow the latest changes/updates to these web standards? Something more user friendly...

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.html5rocks.com/ and http://developers.whatwg.org/ ?

Comment: You can also try here: http://www.webplatform.org/

Comment: **@VKen and Caelea:** I already follow html5rocks.com and webplatform.org, but aren't they basically 'documentation'-kinda sites?

Comment: Updates to the standards, unfortunately, as you've mentioned are done in those drafts, and they keep changing. I have personally relied on other sites such as http://html5doctor.com/ to look at new stuff appearing, and how it is generally used. I don't think looking at changes in the specs is very useful, I'll always look at http://caniuse.com/ to check which browser has implemented which specs.

Comment: You probably want the Web Developer edition of the HTML5 spec, which although still quite daunting, is much less so than the full spec which contains lots of information that only browser makers need to know. Unfortunately the new editors of the W3C HTML5 spec are struggling to get to grips with the generation process of these documents at the current time, and so they are currently broken, with the web developer edition being completely missing. Hopefully, they will have it fixed soon.

Comment: [keeping up with html5 and browser support](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/10/Keeping-up-with-HTML5-and-browser-support)

Comment: @Alohci By Web Developer edition of the HTML5 spec, you were referring to [this](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/) or [this](http://developers.whatwg.org/)?

Comment: @GionaF that'd make a great answer, IMHO.

Comment: @its_me - No. The first is an abandoned 2009 document. There's this document: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-author-20120329/. which is the last officially published version of the document to which I refer, but that's from March this year. To really keep up to date, you want the editor's draft equivalent of that, which should be no more than a few days old. It's that document which is missing. It's the W3C equivalent of the WHATWG document to which you link, but that's really just a download of what Hixie currently thinks, not a document which has been been properly scrutinized.

Comment: @Alohci Ah, okay. Let me check if I understand it right. This page (`http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/`) is supposed to show the latest scrutinized version of the Web Developer edition of the HTML5 spec, but as of now, it isn't. Correct? So, among other links mentioned in the comments, I will keep an eye on this document. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd stay away from w3schools - They are not affiliated with the W3C. See http://w3fools.com/ for details.

Some better, and much more reliable resources are:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc (geared towards beginners - see HTML5 section)

&

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML5
(a bit more on the intermediate level)

Comment: (These will make this answer complete.) Checkout [Keeping up with HTML5 and browser support](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/10/Keeping-up-with-HTML5-and-browser-support), [webplatform.org](http://www.webplatform.org/), [html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/), [developers.whatwg.org](http://developers.whatwg.org/), [html5doctor.com](http://html5doctor.com/), and the [official Web Developer edition of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/)